# Fast algorithm for LU factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

If A is a symmetric matrix, is there a fast algorithm for LU factorization? I know this algorithm for non-symmetric matrix.

```
    For k = 1,..,n
       For i = k + 1,...,n
         mult := a_{ik}/a_{kk}
         a_{jk} := mult
         For j = k+1,...,n
             a_{ij} := a_{ij} - mult * a_{kj}
         Endfor
     Endfor
   Endfor
```

Comment: Look up the $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ and Cholesky decompositions. Of course, these method will only work if all the leading submatrices of your symmetric matrix are nonsingular; otherwise, (symmetric) pivoting is necessary.

Comment: Use Lapack. $    $

Answer (score 1):

See [Wikipedia article,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Symmetric_positive_definite_matrices) try using [Cholesky decomposition.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)

Added Later: The matrix has to be positive definite. So this is just a partial answer to the question.

Comment: Of course, Cholesky won't work if the symmetric matrix is not positive definite...

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that's correct. Sorry. I need to add a condition that the matrix is positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

The cholesky-decomposition can be made "robust" - just keep track of zeros and negative signs in the diagonal. 
Here is a code-snippet in my (proprietary,sorry) MatMate-language, which should be easily translatable into a *C*- or *Basic* - or something-else routine:

```
TMP = X           // X is the symmetric matrix
L   = Null(X)     // Null-matrix of same size as X;
                  //         shall become the cholesky-factor
sg  = L[*,1]      // vector which keeps track of the signs in the diagonal
 c  = 0           // index for the current column/row  

 // repeat the following up to the number of rows/colums of X
c=c+1            
d = w(TMP[c,c])   // the value of the diagonal element TMP[c,c]
            // if zero or lower/equal required precision finish procedure
s = sign(d)
sg[c] = s         // store the sign of the diagonal element
L[*,c] = TMP[*,c]/sqrt(s*d)  // fill the c'th column
TMP = TMP - s * L[*,c] * L[*,c]'  // reduce tmp;
                                  //   the apostroph means transposition
```

***Check result:***

```
chk = L * mkdiag(sg) * L'  // check: re-compose cholesky-factors 
                                  // with signed-diagonal
err = X - chk   // should be zero
```

We can even include, that the algorithm terminates when *d* becomes zero: the cholesky-factor **L** reflects then exactly the rank of **X**